# Manage many-to-many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following issue: how to manage a many-to-many association between user and command.
I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users_commands, dependent: :destroy
has_many :commands, :through => :users_commands
end

class Command < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users_commands, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, :through => :users_commands
end

class UsersCommands < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :commands
end
```

Now if i have:

```
@user = User.find_by(id: 1)
@command = Command.find_by(id: 3)
```

1) How can I save their id on the users_commands table?
2) How can I retrieve all the command with user_id =1 later?

I tried with `@user.commands.push(@command)` but I have an error message:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::UsersCommand
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:125:in `compute_type'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:178:in `klass'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `block in source_reflection'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `collect'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:420:in `source_reflection'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:557:in `check_validity!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:9:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:70:in `commands'
from (irb):9
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: For saving the association, try @user.commands.push(@command) or @command.users.push(@user). This will automatically create the join model. For retrieving, I'm assuming you've tried @user.commands and @command.users? Those methods should work assuming your database is set up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models are not declared properly:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_commands, dependent: :destroy
  #            ^        ^
  has_many :commands, :through => :user_commands
  #                                   ^        ^
end

class Command < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_commands, dependent: :destroy
  #            ^        ^
  has_many :users, :through => :user_commands
  #                                ^        ^
end

class UserCommand < ActiveRecord::Base
  #      ^       ^
  belongs_to :user
  #              ^
  belongs_to :command
  #                 ^
end
```

And then create a new command with one of these alternatives:

```
@user.commands.create(attributes_hash)
# or 
command.user_commands.create(user_id: @user.id)
# or
command = Command.find(params[:command_id])
@user = User.find(params[:id])
user_command_relation = UserCommand.create(user_id: @user.id, command_id: command.id)
```

Some **ActiveRecord naming conventions**:

- the model name (class name) should be singular: `User`, not `Users`
- the belongs_to (and has_one) relations should be singular: `belongs_to :user`
- the has_many relations should be plural: `has_many :users`
- A joined model's name used for many-to-many relations should be singular: `UserCommand`
- A has_many relation ith a joined table should be declared as plural: `has_many :user_commands`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you adopt the HABTM association for this. Rails has a great core guide.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference

Once this is done, you can save associations as if it's a direct association and the join record will be created automatically. For example

```
@user.commands.push(@command)
```

or you can use

```
command = @user.commands.new(attributes)
command.save
```

and the created Command instance will include a join to your user.

Answer (score -1):

One problem off the bat is

```
class UsersCommands < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :commands
end
```

They should be singularized as per Rails convention, so change to

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :command
```